# Mysql query parameter binding issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to run a mysql query to SELECT rows based on the ID's provided, here is the query:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT guid FROM bicp_posts WHERE ID IN (%s)", $gallery[0]));
```

The $gallery[0] variable contains a string as: "1440,1439,1417"

**Problem:**
When I execute this query it gives me only one row in result instead of 3 rows, For debugging purpose I displayed the last executed query and it shows this executed query:

**SELECT guid FROM bicp_posts WHERE ID IN ('1440,1439,1417');**

Notice the commas inside IN brackets are the problem as the following query gives correct results: (without commas in brackets)

**SELECT guid FROM bicp_posts WHERE ID IN (1440,1439,1417);**

How can I bind the string in the query such that it is without the commas like the query written right above this sentence so that I can get correct results.

Comment: The commas are not the problem, they are required. The problem is that you are passing a single string containing `'1440,1439,1417'` when you should be passing 3 distinct numbers `1440,1439,1417`

Comment: this would also work `SELECT guid FROM bicp_posts WHERE ID IN ('1440','1439','1417');`